# move a sprite to match borders of a circle in xna

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

i'm trying to build a game in xna, i got a circle which i want the player to move around it, as you can see in the following picture, its working great except the drawing part which i'm not pleased with
here's a link to an image http://s12.postimage.org/poiip0gtp/circle.png

i want to center the player object to the edge of the circle so it won't look like the player is standing on air

this is how i calculate the position of the player

```
rad = (degree * Math.PI / 180);
            rotationDegree = (float)((Math.PI * degree) / 180);
            currentPosition.X = (float)(Math.Cos(rad) * Earth.radius + (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2));
            currentPosition.Y = (float)(Math.Sin(rad) * Earth.radius + (GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2));
```

and this is how i draw the player

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture,currentPosition, null, Color.White,rotationDegree, Vector2.Zero,1f,SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the origin overload for spritebatch. Which is where the sprite is drawn according to the position.

```
Spritebatch.Draw(texture,Position, null,Color.White,0f,new Vector2(texture.Width / 2,texture.Height /2),1f,SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Using `texture.Width / 2,texture.Height /2` for origin will center it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do here is adjust the sprite's `origin`, which is the vector that you're passing into `SpriteBatch.Draw()`.  This is used to determine the "center point" of your sprite; `{0, 0}` represents the sprite's upper-left corner, while `{spriteWidth, spriteHeight}` represents the bottom-right corner.  Your sprite will be positioned and rotated relative to this origin.